# Provide a button in the editor to insert a sound to an answer

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado

It would be better if you can directly record the sound using the client's microphone, but if that's not possible, a upload dialog similar to the image will be sufficient.

Sure all of questions in the [pronunciación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciacion) tag would benefit from that adition.

I think also the others X Language and Usage sites in the SE network will welcome that feature.

## How it works

### while writing an answer

First, the editor features a new button:

[image]

When the button is clicked, a *dialog* is shown:

[image]

The dialog function basically the same as the image dialog. Bonus points if the server supports automatic windows audio (wma produced by standard sound recorder) to mp3 conversion.

The url of the sound is referenced the same way as a regular link in markdown. I'm not too sure here about if

- Markdown have any *standard* way to reference a sound (if not it looks like a 
  nice adition, given the html5 standard sound support).
- if not, then what's better

  - to reference it using the same exclamation sign like the images,
  - to use other char to *identify* the link as a sound, using similar syntax, for example:

    ```
    *[Pronunciación de **RAE**, acento centroaméricano][3]
    ```

### while displaying an answer

The markdown to html converter will produce the needed markup to let the user hear the audio, for example:

```
    <figure>
      <audio controls>
        <source src="http://a.mp3ur.com/ueDY4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <figcaption>Pronunciación de <strong>RAE</strong>, acento centroaméricano<figcaption>
      </audio>
    </figure>
```

The answer then will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/58/embedded-audio-player/176#176

Comment: @Joul I wasn't aware of that player. I see it's not enabled for this site, and the other thing I see is the _audio hosting_ site welcomes music, but I'm not sure about a small audio containing single words or sentences.

Comment: +1 This is a great idea.

Comment: Marking as completed for now - even though it's not exactly how you proposed it. I like your proposed implementation better, as we begin graduating more language oriented sites, building something closer to what you described is something I'm definitely bringing up again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't quite have this as you described, but we [can easily enable SoundCloud](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/youtube-and-soundcloud-embedding-is-now-enabled) for this purpose. You'd just need to record the sound byte, upload it to SoundCloud and then it would be easy to play from directly within a post.

I've enabled this for Spanish Stack Exchange now - you can use it right away (only SoundCloud, not YouTube) on a trial basis to see how it works for you. This is something we're considering enabling for language sites by default, we'd love for you to give it a try and let us know what you think.

***Make sure to use http://, not https:// links to SoundCloud*** - a bug in the plugin won't recognize SSL links, we're working on it.

Note - it's not enabled here on your meta site, just on the main site.

Comment: Great!!! Thanks! :)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand well how this works, but I tried in this answer with no luck: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3138/como-se-pronuncia-rae/3139#3139

Comment: @jachguate I'm looking into it now. That should have boxed with the playback button and stuff.

Comment: It's a minor glitch in the plugin - https:// links elude it, just use http:// (for now).

Comment: Got it, thanks again, it's a very nice work ;)